# Cannot stop and (re-play) a rtsp stream with FFMediaElement

Tags: c#, wpf, ffmpeg

I have a problem using stop and play on a rtsp stream using the FFMediaElement.

I am initializing an instance of the MediaElement once by doing `m_MediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();`
This instance should live the whole application lifetime.

After this, I open the rtsp stream: `await m_MediaPlayer.Open(new Uri(rtspAdress));`
The media opens, and when I do `m_MediaPlayer.Play();` the stream is displayed in the MediaElement.

Now I want to stop the stream with `m_MediaPlayer.Stop();` and play it again. After calling play again, the stream is not diplayed anymore. The log says:

Direct Command 'Close' accepted. Perparing execution.
OnStreamReadInterrupt was requested an immediate read exit.
EVENT START: BufferingEnded
EVENT DONE : BufferingEnded
V BLK: 14.388 | CLK: 14.417 | DFT: 29 | IX: 4 | RNG: 48.897% | PQ: 0.0k | TQ: 0.0k
Direct Command 'Close' entered
MediaState changed: + Close
Media closed.
OnStreamReadInterrupt was requested an immediate read exit.
EVENT START: MediaStateChanged
EVENT START: MediaClosed
EVENT DONE : MediaStateChanged
Direct Command 'Close' completed. Result: True
EVENT DONE : MediaClosed
Dispose Entered. Waiting for Command Manager processor to stop.
Dispose is waiting for pending direct commands.
Dispose is closing media.
EVENT START: MediaClosed
Media closed.
EVENT DONE : MediaClosed
Dispose completed.

So why is Stop disposing the media?
When I create a new player before re-playing and open the stream again, it works. But this takes a moment, so I just wat to stop and start again. Is that possible?